# Explosion animation of a View in android

Tags: android, android-animation

I'd like to animate a View (for example a Button, ImageView) that it would appear to be exploding, as with by a bomb. What would be the best approach to implement this? Overlay an explosion frame-based animated sprite over the view? Or is there a possibility to implement this in code somehow?

Comment: I think u better to use drawable animation(frame by frame).

Comment: I remember Ander Web sharing this a while back. It's what you're looking for. [https://github.com/AnderWeb/Sample-Projects/tree/master/explodeTest/src/com/example/explodetest](https://github.com/AnderWeb/Sample-Projects/tree/master/explodeTest/src/com/example/explodetest)

Comment: @aneal - exactly that!. Make it an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the '[ExplosionField](https://github.com/tyrantgit/ExplosionField)' library, it makes it very straightforward. Good luck!

Gradle:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'tyrantgit:explosionfield:1.0.1'
 }
```

Usage:

```
ExplosionField explosionField = ...;
explosionField.explode(view);
```

Comment: how to use this lib. As this crashes my application.

Comment: any fix for [this](https://github.com/tyrantgit/ExplosionField/issues/30) issue in same library ?
Thanks